# draggable div is not editable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jquery UI `Draggable` and `Contenteditable` not working together on the same `Div` element. Is there any workaround for this?

Example : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EexHH/)

Comment: You sure are in an asking spree.

Comment: please http://jsfiddle.net/EexHH/ check this fiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why is the jQuery draggable is hijacking click event of the element. You can use this fix inside your code:

```
$('.edit').draggable().bind('click', function(){
  $(this).focus();
})
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EexHH/3/

Comment: Thanks for you and `KRULE` for this answer :)